# SQL trigger to insert value into same row with value from another table on insert or update

Tags: sql-server, triggers, lookup-tables

When a new record is inserted in `dbo.BOM`, or when my column `BOM.Site` is updated, I want to lookup the `BOM.Site` value in `dbo.SiteMap`, and bring back the `SiteMap.SiteName` value and insert it into the `BOM.SiteMap` column. So I thought a trigger would be the way to go but it does not work. (If a trigger is not the best apporach to this please let me know!) Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Tables:

```
=BOM=
id |  Site    | SiteMap
---+----------+------
 1 |    Mex   | 
 2 |    MXN   | 
 3 |    USA   | 
 4 |    Mex   | 


=SiteMap=
id | SiteName | Sitecode
---+----------+------
 1 | Mexico   | Mex
 2 | Mexico   | MXN
 3 | USA      | USA
 4 | USA      | United States of America
```

Desired output:

```
=BOM=
id |  Site    | SiteMap
---+----------+------
 1 |    Mex   | Mexico
 2 |    MXN   | Mexico
 3 |    USA   | United States of America
 4 |    Mex   | Mexico
```

I've tried a couple of different things..

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trMapBom on dbo.BOM
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE([Site ])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.BOM
        SET BOM.[Site Map] = 
        (
            SELECT [SiteName]
            from dbo.SiteMap
            where [PlantCode] = [Site ]
        )
    END
END
GO
```

Another try..

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trMapBom on dbo.BOM
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.BOM set [Site ] = SiteMap.SiteName
    from dbo.BOM
    inner join dbo.SiteMap
    on BOM.[Site ] = SiteMap.PlantCode

END
GO
```

Comment: I haven't seen `PlantCode` column in your provided table structure. Is it typo or what ? If yes then there should be `Sitecode` column from `SiteMap` table. BTW there is no need to make trigger for this requirement. You can achieve it in your stored procedure (if its there in your app). One more question - Let say when you insert new record into `BOM` table then its related `SiteCode` is always there in `SiteMap` table ? Confirm it first. And What if its related record not exists in `SiteMap` table ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use inserted rows in the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trMapBom on dbo.BOM
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE b 
    set [SiteMap] = sm.SiteName
    from dbo.BOM b
    inner join dbo.SiteMap sm
    on b.[Site] = sm.SiteCode
    inner join inserted i
    on i.id = b.id

END
GO
```